# Can't set a .lnk file to hidden

Tags: windows, cmd, hyperlink, attributes

I am trying to make a .lnk file hidden using the command line (windows 10). I try "attrib +h filename.lnk" in the command line however it doesn't make the .lnk file hidden. Instead it makes the file that the .lnk file is linked to hidden. How can I make the .lnk file hidden?

Comment: A hidden shortcut must be a longcut; if you can't see it, it becomes quicker to invoke the linked file directly. I'd like to know the purpose.

Comment: attrib.exe won't operate on the target of a .lnk file. You must be mistaking a symbolic link for a .lnk file. Use `attrib.exe +h filename /L` to operate on the symbolic link instead of its target.

Comment: That worked perfetly eryksun thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For others looking for the answer to this in the future, Eryksuns comment:

```
attrib.exe +h filename /L
```